# Неправильная подгрузка на ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

В общем такое дело, подгружаю табличку на ajax, данные в обычном html, тупо подхватываю ее и добавляю в конец необходимого блока. В зависимости от передаваемых GET-параметров генерирую необходимые данные. Но вот в чем проблема: подгружает не то, что нужно! Т.е. данные, генерируемые на странице не совпадают с тем, что подхватывает ajax! Проверял довольно просто: захожу на страницу, откуда подгружаю аяксом, и сравниваю.
Ниже привожу пример скрипта:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/load_videos/",
    data: tst,
    dataType: "html",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        $("#table-div").append(data);
    }
});
```

Где "tst" - передаваемые параметры(обычная строка GET-запроса).
Во вьюхе обычный обработчик висит, думаю нет смысла его показывать.
Куда копать, что где может быть не так? Занятно, что когда идет пустой GET-запрос, то проблем нету, подгружает правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка найдена... Неверно передавал в ф-ию ajax() параметр 'data'.
Передавал в виде

```
'?key1=value1&key2=value2'
```

а нужно было без "?", т.е. в виде

```
'key1=value1&key2=value2'
```

Вот такая казалось бы мелочь... Странное отличие, почему-то думал что строка должна быть как при обычном GET-запросе :)

Comment: @ХэшКод Примите мой ответ на вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Может попробовать POST метод?

Comment: Я сейчас использую GET что бы можно было отлавливать вот такие ошибки, когда будет метод POST - уже ничего толком не отследишь... Но посчитаю ваше предложение "магическим" и отложу его на самый крайний случай ;)

Answer (score 0):

А можете привести пример переменной tst? В ней должне быть объект, который содержет в себе набор key/value.

Comment: В ней может быть либо объект key/value, либо строка. Я же выше (в правильном ответе) показал что и куда. У меня такие строки проскакивают: 'sort=popular&page=2' и иже с ними.